# Can't access class in nested ruby modules

Tags: ruby, class, module, nested

I'm fighting with nested modules and access to classes in these modules in ruby.

I created a simple example to show my problem. *app.rb* and *test.rb* are placed in the same folder while *sub_test.rb* is placed in a sub-folder called *test*.

**app.rb**

```
# /app.rb
require_relative 'test.rb'

Test::NotWorkingClass.work
```

**test.rb**

```
# /test.rb
module Test
  require_relative 'test/sub_test'

  class NotWorkingClass
    def self.work
      puts 'Test::NotWorkingClass.work'
    end
  end
end
```

**test/sub_test.rb**

```
# /test/sub_test.rb
module Test
  module SubTest
    Test::NotWorkingClass.work
  end
end
```

When executing the app I'm getting this error:

```
/test/sub_test.rb:3:in `<module:SubTest>': uninitialized constant Test::NotWorkingClass (NameError)
```

When I commented out the execution of *Test::NotWorkingClass* in *sub_test.rb* everything works fine.

And now the strange thing I didn't understand. I modified my example by creating a file called *not_working_class.rb* in *test* folder and include it in the test.rb file:

**test.rb**

```
# /test.rb
module Test
    require_relative 'test/not_working_class'
    require_relative 'test/sub_test'
end
```

**test/not_working_class.rb**

```
# /test/not_working_class.rb
module Test
  class NotWorkingClass
    def self.work
      puts 'Test::NotWorkingClass.work'
    end
  end
end
```

And now, the example works.

So why can't I access Classes defined in the test.rb file but can access them when defined in separate file?

Comment: As an aside, `require`s should (almost always) go at the top of your file, not inside your `module`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, *test/sub_test.rb* can not find `Test::NotWorkingClass`.

You should add `require_relative "../test"` in *test/sub_test.rb*, and remove the `require_relative 'test/sub_test'` in *test.rb*

Comment: I don't like this solution. It's a simplified example but when I would have 20 files in test-folder I would need to include all of them in app.rb. But what I wan't to achieve is to only require one file in app.rb - not 20. Because the "test" should be a library which I wanna use in different places. Isn't there an other solution?

Comment: @PascalTurbo In your OP, the "require" is not right, subtest has no idea what `NotWorkingClass` is if you does not require "test". As you said, "test" is a library, a library is something you should require in another file. Actually, I don't understand your code logic here, what does sub_test do, without it, the code works just fine. I am not sure why you want to include all files under test in app.rb, but you can try something like `Dir.glob("test/*.rb") { |f| require f }`.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is where the require statement is at.

If you put `require_relative "../test"` inside test/sub_test.rb it creates circular require because test.rb requires test/sub_test.rb

If you put `require_relative "../test"` inside test/sub_test.rb and then add `require_relative "test/sub_test.rb"` inside app.rb then it'll work